# Tensorflow: ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am confused as of why the following functions throws the error `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable`.

```py
@tf.function
def train_network(model, optimizer, states, actions, rewards):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        predictions = model(states)
        indices = tf.stack([tf.range(predictions.shape[0], dtype=tf.int64), actions], axis=1)
        action_rewards = tf.scatter_nd(indices, rewards, predictions.shape)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.MSE(predictions, action_rewards)
    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))
    return loss
```

I pass the model and optimizer because they are part of a class-object. But as I found you cannot have a tf.function as a class-function.

If I try the same thing with a keras fit function it works just fine, eg. `self.model.fit(np.array(states_epoch), np.array(rewards_epoch), batch_size=50)`.

I want to run it with a tf function because my training is actually more complex but for this example I slimmed it down as much as possible.

More info:

states are float32, actions is a list of integers of actions took, reward is a list of integers of received rewards.

The network is a simple DNN, optimizer is keras.

Comment: I found that the problem was acutally that i was passing in the model and optimizer as parameters, this did not work. Is there a solution though to have it part of a class? How do I reference the tf.function if i do not pass it in?

Comment: Hi! can you please provide the complete code with Dataset or a Colab gist ? That would be really helpful to expedite the issue.